# Azure AD configuration for access API Resources and Web application in an on premisses server

Tags: azure, authentication

I have a Java web application with an angular front (inserted in the application jar) and an Api to be consumed by a mobile app in flutter.

This application worked normally on an on-premises server, but Azure AD protection was placed on it. After that, the web application works normally, authenticating with browser cookies, but access to the api has been blocked. I've tried setting up API access via Postman, but to no avail.

Could anyone help? How to configure access to this api via mobile?

I've tried to expose the api and even get an access token, but when I make the request to the api resource it returns an html requesting login even though the access token was placed in the authorization header.